# JQuery validation is not working with ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Can`t get why my JQuery validation is not working on my ProjectName field, it allows to post null values, may be the reason is that action is called with ajax and all the data are set without submitting the form? 
Here is my Model:

```
{
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Display(Name = "project_name", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "project_description", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "system_kind", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string SystemType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "project_manager", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string ProjectManager { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "project_type", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "fixed_bid", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public bool FixedBid { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TM", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public bool TimeAndMaterials { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TillDate { get; set; }
}
```

and the View I work on:

```
    @model BTGHRM.Models.ProjectViewModel

<link href="~/Content/themes/custom/MyCustom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#postToServ").click(function () {

            var dataObject = {
                ProjectName: $("#ProjectName").val(),
                ProjectDescription: $("#ProjectDescription").val(),
                SystemType: $("#SystemType").val(),
                ProjectManager: $("#ProjectManager").val(),
                FixedBid: $("#FixedBid").val(),
                TimeAndMaterials: $("#TimeAndMaterials").val(),
                StartDate: $("#datepicker").val(),
                TillDate: $("#datepicker1").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Project/ProjectRegistration",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataObject,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    $("#loading_content").html("<br><b>"+"@Resources.Localization.data_successfully_saved"+"!</b>");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Unable to save! Try again");

                }
            });

        })
    })
</script>

<span class="content_h4">@Resources.Localization.register_project</span>
<br /><br />

    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { id="MyForm"}))
    {
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectName):</b>
                </td>
                <td style="width:80%">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectName, new { style = "width:80%"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectDescription):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProjectDescription, new { style = "width:80%; height:110px" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            //some similar code
    </table>
    <br />
    <div style="width:100%">
        <input type="button" id="postToServ" value=@Resources.Localization.save style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left:50%;">
    </div>

}
<div id="loading_content"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the validation?

Comment: [Required] attribute in a model

Comment: And shouldn't you be listening for the submit of the form?

Comment: Nope, cause I d like my JS to post info to server, or you mean that this attribute wont trigger without submitting form.

Comment: The validation code has no clue you are adding a click to a button and doing some action. How is it supposed to prevent it? Does the code have a validate method or is there an error class you can look for to see if it is valid? You are going to have to do some sort of check, it is not going to be free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

Points to note:

1. Handle the "submit" event of the form instead of the button click
2. Serialize the form using jQuery. Then you don't have to pick out each form element separately, or change your code when your fields change in future.
3. Call the form validation method manually and check the outcome before making the ajax call.
4. Additionally I've made the "error" function compliant with the jQuery documenation.

Replace

```
 <input type="button" id="postToServ" ...
```

with

```
<input type="submit" id="postToServ" ...
```

and then setup your script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); //stop default postback behaviour

      var valid = $(this).valid(); //run form validation manually

      if (valid == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Project/ProjectRegistration",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // automatically read all the form data and convert to correct format for posting to server
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#loading_content").html("<br><b>"+"@Resources.Localization.data_successfully_saved"+"!</b>");
            },
            error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
       }
    });
});
</script>
```